# Find index of pointer array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am looking at something with a pointer that is acting like a buffer for data with an array size of about 800. It is looping and placing sets of data in order at various indexes.

Say we have 1001 and a space then 0110 it will then fill the buffer with "1001 0110 1001 0110 1001" and so on...

So what I want to do is find the index it is currently at and change it say from "1001 0110" to something like "0101 0110 0101 0110".

So, basically I want to find the index of the buffer and change the data inside before it goes to its output routine.

Here is what something like I am looking at:

```
char *p1;
char p2[800];
int setIndex = 0;

if (p1 >= &p2[p2_length - 1]) p1 = &p2[0];
else ++p1;
```

What do I set "setIndex" to in order to change the value at where ever p2 is? ex: p2[setIndex], what is setIndex? Do I just set setIndex to the pointer address value or the value at that address? I'm a bit confused. Thank you.

edit:

Answer that worked for me thanks to Barmar.

```
setIndex = p1 - p2;

p2[setIndex] = '1'; //or whatever value you want to change to
```

Comment: "find the index it is currently at": Please explain what this means; an example would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, so there is an array that acts like a buffer, and I want to know where the array index is. For example, int array[800]; and the array index is incrementing constantly and looping back to 0. I need to find where the array is currently positioned and change the data at that index. So, I need to set the index to where ver the array index is at. For example, array[500], I would set "setIndex" to 500.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An array will decay to a pointer when you use it in many types of expressions. So if you want to find the index of a pointer, just subtract the base of the array:

```
setIndex = p1 - p2;
```

Now `p1 == &p2[setIndex]`.

Comment: Worked like a charm so far! Thank you so much!! I'll edit first response with that one :D.

Comment: Note that this works even if the array has elements larger than `char`. I guess it has to do with the ability to add to pointers, which adds the whole size of the element being pointed to. Subtraction works the same way. See C99, 6.5.6§9: "When two pointers are subtracted, [...] the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements."